# SetWindowSubclass function from WinApi

Tags: winapi, mingw

Trying to compile some code that uses SetWindowSubclass function with MinGW, but compiler tells me that there is no such function. Found function's declaration in header file `commctrl.h` and it seems to be excluded by some defines:

[image]

Can I do anything with it?

Comment: [Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers). But the *real* solution is to not use MinGW altogether. It's got all the wrong defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated the same problem using `SetWindowSubclass` in Code::Blocks with MinGW.

It can be seen from the `#if` condition statement that `_WIN32_WINNT` needs to be greater than `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP`(represents Windows XP, Because the Minimum supported client of [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass#requirements)  is windows XP)

In sdkddkver.h, `_WIN32_WINNT_WINXP` is defined as:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP  0x0501      /* Windows XP */
```

So we need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` greater than `0x501`:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x502
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
```

The lib you should link in MinGW for this api is `libcomctl32.a`.

In addition, it is recommended to use MSVC and VS tool, which can define these macros correctly.